# Marlin: How to print to terminal to debug?

Tags: marlin

I am looking for the equivalent of `System.out.println()` or `Console.WriteLine()`, but using `M118`.

For example, every time a particular variable changes its value I want to send a message to the terminal in OctoPrint as if it were sent by `M118`.

These commands would be hardcoded into the firmware files before compiling/flashing.

Since `M118.cpp` is only designed to parse a string given by the user I am not quite clear how to co-opt it for this use.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please find the answer [here](https://reprap.org/forum/read.php?415,822581). If it works make your own answer, else I might do it later.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the option to edit the source code or is recompilation not an option for you? I'd just edit the `M118` function to print your variable when a specific text is given. You could have it print different variables per text that is supplied.

A more fancy way would be to copy and alter the `M118` to an unused function (above 1000 seems unused) to match your needs.